# How can I dynamically get tooltip using converter?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

If I run my project, my tooltip converter is run once - I need it to run each time the mouse hoover over a row.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyTooltipConverter x:Key="MyTooltipConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="263" Width="507">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ToolTip Content="{Binding ??, Converter={StaticResource MyTooltipConverter}}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And code...

```
Imports System.Globalization

Class MainWindow

    Public Class Person
        Public Property Name As String
    End Class

    Public Persons As New List(Of Person)

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        For i As Integer = 0 To 5
            Persons.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Test " + i.ToString})
        Next
        dataGrid.DataContext = Persons
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class MyTooltipConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        If value Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim panel As New StackPanel()
        panel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical

        Dim block As New TextBlock()
        block.Text = Now.ToString
        panel.Children.Add(block)

        Dim tip As New ToolTip()
        tip.Content = panel

        Return tip
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

How can I call MyTooltipConveter af get a Tooltip with the current time?

Thanks

Comment: You should add datatemplate for each item and define tooltip afterwards I guess. Inside datatemplate you might use sth like this.

   <Button.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Loc CreatePrePayAccount}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Loc CreatePrePayAccountDescr}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Button.ToolTip>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your MyTooltipConverter.Convert method to Return panel. Returning tip throws a System.InvalidOperationException - 'ToolTip' cannot have a logical or visual parent.

As for the binding, just using the converter works.

```
<ToolTip Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyTooltipConverter}}" />
```

Of course, for the time to update you have to move the mouse around to generate a new tooltip. If what you wanted was to have a tooltip that constantly updates then you need to add a timer and update the block.Text.

Something like this:

```
Public Class MyTooltipConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        If value Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim panel = New StackPanel()
        panel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical

        Dim block As New TextBlock()
        block.Text = Now.ToString
        panel.Children.Add(block)

        Dim timer As New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()
        timer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
        AddHandler timer.Tick, Sub()
                                   block.Text = Now.ToString
                               End Sub
        timer.Start()
        Debug.WriteLine("Timer Started")

        AddHandler panel.Unloaded, Sub(s, e)
                                       timer.Stop()
                                       timer = Nothing
                                       panel = Nothing
                                       Debug.WriteLine("Timer Stopped")
                                   End Sub

        Return panel
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Wow - thanks! I really appreciate your help! Have been trying to figure it out all day, so your help means a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. I sometimes learn when I help others so I see it as a mutual benefit. For instance, I usually code in C# so I just learned how to add event handlers and 'anonymous' methods in VB.